# SQL Server return 1 rows affected when null returned from a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, null

I have an alert service which triggers when a SQL statement returns more than one row. Select statements from a view is added to this alert service.

Since I am calling a function from a view, it always returns a row, even if it is null. Is there any way to return  0 rows affected (when function returns null)?

```
Mappings
-------------------------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I want this to be

```
Mappings
-------------------------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Is there some other meaning which a single record with a `NULL` value has which is stopping you from using that?

Comment: C# code repDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count will return 1 in this situation and triggers the alert; which is to be avoided.

Comment: Add `WHERE Mappings IS NOT NULL` to your existing query?

Comment: Damien, It worked!. Thanks a ton!


select [dbo].GET_PRODUCT_MAPPINGS() as Mappings
where [dbo].GET_PRODUCT_MAPPINGS() IS NOT NULL

Comment: I avoided calling the function twice.


with cte 
as 
(
    select        
        Mappings = GET_PRODUCT_MAPPINGS() 
)
select
   Mappings
from
  cte
where 
    cte.Mappings IS NOT NULL

Comment: Bear in mind that in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. There's no guarantee that your first query would have actually executed the function twice, nor that your second query will avoid calling the function twice.

Comment: Damien, you are right. In fact CTE version took more time, when checked with execution plan and statistics.

Answer (score 0):

select [dbo].GET_PRODUCT_MAPPINGS() as Mappings where [dbo].GET_PRODUCT_MAPPINGS() IS NOT NULL.